CodeQL: Setting paths in Github Advanced Security for Devops
I'm using Github Advanced Security in Azure devops in a monorepo. With the given folder structure:
.
└── apps/
    ├── frontend/
    │   ├── green-app
    │   └── red-app
    └── backend/
        ├── green-app
        └── red-app

By default the codeql task will scan the ENTIRE code base. Which is not what I want.
How can I configure Github advanced security to only scan one project?For example the front-end and backend folder for the green-app.
I tried setting the sources folder to the back-end folder. But then I'm not able to "reach" the front-end folder in the codeqlpathstoinclude parameter.
When I try this:
  - task: AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Init@1
    condition: and(succeededOrFailed(), ${{parameters.runGithubAdvancedSecurity}})
    displayName: 'Github Advanced Security: Initialize '
    inputs:
      languages: 'csharp,javascript'
      sourcesfolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/apps/backend/green-app'
      codeqlpathstoinclude: '../frontend/green-app'

(Following the docs: "The paths must be relative to the sourcesfolder where CodeQL is running, which defaults to the Build.SourcesDirectory pipeline environment variable. For example, to include the $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/app directory, set codeqlpathstoinclude: app rather than codeqlpathstoinclude: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/app.")
I get:

Only found JavaScript or TypeScript files that were empty or contained syntax errors

What am I doing wrong here?
Edit: I tried wildcards as well, but it gave me the same 'no sources found' error:
apps/*/green-app/**/*

